# Mirroring iPad on to MacBook air

Tags: mirroring

I have the latest generation ipad pro and macbook air, but the problem is I want to mirror or share my ipad screen so that it appears on my MacBook air screen so that when i draw on my ipad notes, other people can see what i am drawing through the MacBook air screen.

Is there anything I have to buy or can do so that everything thing i do on my iPad can be shown through my macbook air?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if the iPads with USB-C can do this, but if you connect your iOS device to a Mac, [you can mirror/record your screen with QuickTime Player](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201066#record).

1. Connect your iPad or iOS device to your Mac.
2. Open QuickTime Player.
3. Select File > New Movie Recording.
4. Click the little arrow to the right of the record button and select your iPad from the list.

After this, your iPad's screen will appear on screen. I think the floating recording window will disappear if you don't have your mouse over it.

You may have to trust the computer on your iPad or iOS device to get this to work. The aspect ratio will be preserved on screen, so a portrait iPad would be 3:4 and landscape would be 4:3.

Comment: Thank you I will try this later and update you.